# Cocos2d buttons running actions

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to create buttons in Cocos2d and run actions on them?

e.g. some update code that then changes the image or runs an action?

How does one do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [How To Create Buttons in Cocos2D: Simple, Radio, and Toggle](http://www.raywenderlich.com/414/how-to-create-buttons-in-cocos2d-simple-radio-and-toggle).

This is a code snippet from the tutorial showing the basic:

```
CCMenuItem *starMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage 
  itemFromNormalImage:@"ButtonStar.jpg" selectedImage:@"ButtonStarSel.jpg" 
  target:self selector:@selector(starButtonTapped:)];
starMenuItem.position = ccp(60, 60);
CCMenu *starMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:starMenuItem, nil];
starMenu.position = CGPointZero;
[self addChild:starMenu];
```

Answer (score 0):

the most common way is to create CCMenu with CCMenuItems as buttons. Within CCMenuItems you set action and images (normal, highlighted).